# Isolated audio buzz to computer screen, how to fix?

Tags: noise

I've got a very noticeable and loud buzz. I've got several devices connected - mixer, monitor speakers, audio interface, guitar pedals etc.

To cut to the chase, I've isolated that my (otherwise great) Aorus FV43U screen is causing the nasty buzz whenever its plugged in. I suspect it has a sub-optimal internal power supply.

I've tried many different configurations, tried a Mac laptop doc, tried isolating the audio interface, tried different wall power points, same power points, the whole deal. What is comes down to is whenever the computer monitor is connected to any part of the chain, in comes the buzz/whine. Its not a ground loop, tested for that too.

My question: what can I do about this? is there any way to filter out this noise? The monitor is quite expensive and really good otherwise.

Comment: Is everything correctly earthed? Is it all on the same mains ring [or spur if US]? If you just happen to have an isolating transformer kicking around, try that [they're a bit expensive just to take a punt].

Comment: I've tested it on different power points (at the wall socket) and still getting the issue. i.e. trying to put the screen on its own circuit. Is that the right troubleshooting? I'm not familiar with what a mains ring is.

Comment: Another angle - been doing more research: would a passive direct input box resolve this? Been reading up about DI boxes with a Ground Lift, which purportedly can cut interference. This is all very new to me so unsure about it...

Comment: ok. Bought a DI box (passive, 'hum eliminator'). Will report back what it does.